# Batch remove entries from Multiling dictionary

Tags: dictionary

In the Android dictionary, there are hundreds of abbreviations and all-caps combinations that are hardly ever used.
However, when typing, these words keep popping up instead of the intended words.

The system in question is a non-rooted Android 7, and the keyboard is `Multiling O Keyboard`.
Since apps cannot write to the built-in dictionary, I assume that Multiling stores user dictionary entries (like the addition or removal of words) in a separate file, and compares this file to the built-in dictionary.

Where does Multiling keep its word lists (for each language)?

Is there a way to remove all of these abbreviations and all-caps words, e. g. by batch-processing a list or by replacing a database file?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file in the preferences (gear symbol), then Misc, then Import/Export and there you find the user dictionary.

I’ve written this down, because I’ve been searching so long to find how to backup my user dictionary of the Honso Multiling O Keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. In this file, only the words appear that I have already manually edited (“Save or increase rank” or “Remove or decrease rank” on long-press). For example, if I remove the entry “word”, it will appear in the list as “word::1::en”. But I’m looking to edit the database of all the words in the dictionary, and preferably batch edit it, removing all all-caps words or abbreviations.

Comment: For dictionaries I had to download different additional “apps”, which only include dictionary files (english, spanish, german, icelandic, portuguese, french, …). Maybe you can download those apps and extract their content and find a file that includes all the words? And then built your own apk file. Or just replace the file in the directory structure of your phone, if that is allowed as normal user.